# Optimize comparison and merging of the two lists

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I have two lists of `Bill` objects that have `date` field that represents month when the bill was created. I need to add some objects from `bills` list to `oldBills`. If there are no bill with the same data in `oldBills` list, then bill should be added.

I implemented it this way:

```
outer:
for (Bill bill : bills) {
  Date billDate = bill.getDate();
  for (Bill bill1 : oldBills) {
    Date bill1Date = bill1.getDate();
    if (Objects.equals(billDate, bill1Date)) {
      continue outer;
    }
  }
  newBills.add(bill);
}
oldBills.addAll(newBills);
```

but I think that this is not the best way.

May be you have any ideas, how to optimize this algorithm?

p.s.: java 7

Comment: What makes a bill unique?

Comment: date can be represented with a date object, that means dates can be different for milliseconds... is that ok for you

Comment: If you are trying to look at collisions on the calendar date, use objects of the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class of the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later rather than the old `java.util.Date` class. If you are comparing by calendar month as mentioned, use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the getDate() for a Bill has to be unique, I suggest using a Map which requires a unique key and has an O(1) access for keys.

```
Map<Date, Bill> oldBills = new HashMap<>();
oldBills.putAll(newBills);
```

You could also use a loop

```
for(Bill bill : newBills)
    oldBills.putIfAbsent(bill.getDate(), bill);
```

This will replace all the bills which have the same `Date`. `putAll` is typically an `O(N)` operation where N is the size of `newBills`

You can build these Maps from a List like this.

```
// requires Java 8.
Map<Date, Bill> billByDate = bills.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bill::getDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

If Bill has 'n' elements and oldBill has 'm', your algorithm takes `n * m` iteration. it's `O(n^2)`. It can be improved by sorting oldbill `(O(n*logn) )` and then implementing binary search for each element of bill`(O(logn))`. So, in this case the total time taken would be `O(nlog(n))`.

Comment: isnt n*logn + logn equivalent to n*logn ?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Thank you for pointing that out. That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Bill bill:bills)
    {
        if(!oldBills.contains(bill))
        {
            oldBills.add(bill);
        }

    }
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing with the 'new bills' but this will add bills to oldBills without duplicating record without brute forcing it and having a ^2 algorithm.

Comment: I think that this is the same as my version, because inner loop is if fact a `contains` function

Comment: Yours isn't the same. You're iterating through both loops(n^2) whereas this loops through one, making the computer perform less operations, but gets the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize it by using a HashMap. For this you need to define for your Bill objects a key that is unique. For example the Date and who was payed to

```
public class Bill{
      ...
      public String getKey(){
           return date.toString()+payedTo;
      }
}

HahsMap<String,Bill> oldBills = ...
for (Bill bill : bills){

    if (! oldBills.containsKey(bill.getKey()){
          oldBill.put(bill.getKey(),bill)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of going through loops, it's enough to use the java.util.ArrayList.contains(Object o) which return a boolean.